# can't make highlight js work in meteor js

Tags: javascript, meteor, syntax-highlighting

I have a webpage displaying some posts which have some code in them. I'm trying to use highlight js to highlight the code. however, I still can't make it work after a few hours. It's my first day with Meteor, so the code was adapted from the tutorial on their site. The whole project is quite simple, here is my main js file:

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection("posts");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    // This code only runs on the client
    Template.body.helpers({
      posts: function () {
        return Posts.find({}, {limit: 15});
      }
    });

    Template.post.rendered = function(){
      $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
        hljs.highlightBlock(block);
      });
    };
}
```

The html file I'm using is:

```
<head>
  <title>Posts</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Posts</h1>
    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each posts}}
        {{> post}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="post">
    <h1 class="text">{{title}}</h1>
    {{{ content }}}
</template>
```

I also have a x code style css file from highlight js' github repo in the project. After the page loaded, `hljs` was added to the code tag as a class value, but the code inside the code tag remained unchanged, as you can see in the following image. 
[image: code unchanged]

Any idea why highlight js didn't it change the code?

I'll add more information if my description is not clear enough.

Comment: Would help to have a [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/) demo.

Comment: @FlorianF. Hi, I went there, made an demo and it worked on there. So I restructured my project like the demo project and it worked as well. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

@Gnijuohz

I have a Demo using `highlight` package.

Here is the [Source Code](https://github.com/Ethaan/meteor-editor) and the [DEMO](http://sotexteditor.meteor.com)

This is how i use it.

*Meteor-Version < 1.1*

```
Template.example.rendered = function(){  

  /*
   Higligth Configuration using 
   https://highlightjs.org
  */
    hljs.configure({
       tabReplace: '    ', 
       classPrefix: '',
      useBR:true

    })
     $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
     hljs.highlightBlock(block);
    });

  }
```

*On new Meteor version (1.1).*

```
Template.example.onRendered(function(){
/*
       Higligth Configuration using 
       https://highlightjs.org
      */
        hljs.configure({
           tabReplace: '    ', 
           classPrefix: '',
          useBR:true

        })
         $('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
         hljs.highlightBlock(block);
        });
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually solved it and answered the question already.

Comment: I can not get highlighter.js working without "Uncaught ReferenceError: hljs is not defined" error in console. I came here and all links on all answers are broken. The scripts above do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I tried to make a demo on [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/i7tuxRfhzv2P2pnAm/Leaderboard) as suggested by @Florian, and it worked somehow on there.
So I went back to my project and restructured it like the demo project on meteorpad, somehow it worked.  I ended up using the `simple:highlight` package [here](http://libraries.io/meteor/wilddeer:highlight.js/1.0.10).